# MySql: Order of "WHERE" conditions matters when selecting from 2 (or more) tables?

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables:
"users": (id, name, ...)
"games": (id, player1id, player2id, date, ...)

i want to list the X last games for a specific player, i do:

```
SELECT u.name as p1, u2.name as p2, g.timestamp as time
FROM games g, users u, users u2
WHERE (g.player1id = xyz OR g.player2id = xyz) and u.id = g.player1id and u2.id = g.player2id ORDER BY ...
```

now i wonder, is it important in which order i place those WHERE conditions ? Those tables are several thousand entried and the query seems to take quite a while, so i guess somethings wrong, is this actually the right way to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of `WHERE` condition doesn't matter.
If you want to optimize that query try `EXPLAIN`.

Most likely you dont have indexes on the fields used in the `WHERE`

Comment: Agreed, check for indexing.